# Mastermind Game Code in Python

Tags: python

I am creating a mastermind style game for python, so far I've modified one I found online and have fixed most of the errors but it wont run in python, for example it wont accept the `random.randint()` expression which I found online.

Mainly it just wants checking over and I would appreciate it if you point out any mistakes you find and maybe post some advice?

Here is my code:

```
print("-----------------------------------MASTERMIND-----------------------------------")

colours = ['B', 'R', 'Y', 'G', 'O']

secretCode = ('BYRG')

i = 0
while i < 4:
    colour = random.randint(0, 5)
    secretCode.append(colours[colour])
    i = i+1
print("Secret: "), secretCode

fullMatches = 0
guessNum = 1
while (fullMatches <= 4):
    fullMatches = 0
    partialMatches = 0
    secretCodeCopy = secretCode[:]
    guess = []
    print("Guess:"),  guessNum

    i = 0
    while i < len(secretCode):
        print("Enter your 4 colour guess from:")
        print(colours)
    colour = raw_input()
    guess.append(colour)
    i = i+1

    i = 0
    while i < len(guess):
        if guess[i] == secretCodeCopy[i]:
            fullMatches = fullMatches + 1
            secretCodeCopy[i] = 'X'
            guess[i] = 'Y'
        i = i+1

i = 0
while i < len(guess):
    j = 0
    while j < len(secretCodeCopy):
        if guess[i] == secretCodeCopy[j]:
            partialMatches = partialMatches + 1
            secretCodeCopy[j] = 'X'
            guess[i] = 'Y'
        j = j+1
    i = i+1

print(fullMatches,)
print(" blacks")
print(partialMatches,)
print(" whites")
if fullMatches == 4:
    print("You guessed it in",)
    print(guessNum)
guessNum = guessNum+1
```

Comment: Judging by the fact that you didn't even `import random`, I'm going to guess that you're trying to make a Python app before learning Python - which, as you've found out, really doesn't work. I recommend the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Don't be so harch, although I agree that he should read some more, but let's help him with his random at least (which you maybe did)

Comment: There's a bunch of indentation errors, might have been caused by pasting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the randint() method correctly, but you can't append a char to a string. Your first while loop for example will work if you change code as follows:

```
import random

print("---------------------------------MASTERMIND-----------------------------------")

colours = ['B', 'R', 'Y', 'G', 'O']

secretCode = 'BYRG'

i = 0
while i < 4:
    colour = random.randint(0, 5)
    secretCode += colours[colour]
    i = i+1
print("Secret: "), secretCode
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of problems in your code:

- you need to add `import random` (before the first print statement)
- change `secretCode = ('BYRG')` to `secretCode = []`
- fix indentation
- in the second while change `fullMatches <= 4` to `fullMatches < 4`

Clearly this has not been written by someone very fluent in python. First thing you should learn, perhaps, is to use `xrange` to implement a for loop, instead of while loops with explicit variable initialization and increment, e.g. the first while can be written as:

```
for i in xrange(0, 4):
    colour = random.randint(0, 5)
    secretCode.append(colours[colour])
```

Comment: Judging by the parentheses with every `print`, I'd say the OP is using Python 3, which uses `range` instead of `xrange`.

Answer (score 0):

You used the `random.randint()` correctly, but you need to [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module.

At the beginning of the code, type:

```
import random
```